# Why isn't the UpdatePanel found to update the data

Tags: c#, asp.net, updatepanel

I have the following code in my ASP.net page:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" UpdateMode="Conditional" ID="upClickShowTask">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:LinkButton ID="lbShowTask" CssClass="btnExport" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" Text="Generate Tasks" OnClick="btnFilter_Click"></asp:LinkButton>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>

<asp:Panel ID="pageTab8" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server">
    <asp:Panel ID="demoCli" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" BorderWidth="2" BorderColor="#FF0000">
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="upGenTaskCli" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional" ClientIDMode="Static">
            <ContentTemplate>
                Client: <asp:Label ID="lblCli" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
                <br />
                Onboarding Date: <asp:Label ID="lblCliDate" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
                <br />
                Contact Information: <asp:Label ID="lblCliCont" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
                <br />
                Notes: <asp:Label ID="lblCliNotes" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" Text=""></asp:Label>
                <br />
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
    </asp:Panel>
</asp:Panel>
```

The code-behind:

```
protected void btnFilter_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    demoCli.Visible = false;
    demoSit.Visible = false;
    demoPra.Visible = false;
    demoPro.Visible = false;
        connString = @""; //my connection string
        #region queries
        string queryCli = @"SELECT
                           C.OBJECTID
                           ,C.ATTR2815 'Client'
                           ,C.ATTR2881 'Onboarding Date'
                           ,C.ATTR2880 'Contact Information'
                           ,M.MEMO 'Notes'
                            FROM HSI.RMOBJECTINSTANCE1231 C INNER JOIN HSI.RMMEMO M ON C.MK2879 = M.MEMOID";
        string querySit = @"SELECT
                           S.OBJECTID
                           ,S.ATTR2819 'Site'
                           ,S.FK2820 'RelatedClient'
                           ,S.ATTR2873 'Address'
                           ,S.ATTR2874 'City'
                           ,S.ATTR2875 'State'
                           ,S.ATTR2876 'Zip'
                           ,M.MEMO 'Notes'
                           ,S.ATTR2878 'Onboarding Date'
                            FROM HSI.RMOBJECTINSTANCE1229 S INNER JOIN HSI.RMMEMO M ON S.MK2877 = M.MEMOID";
        string queryPra = @"SELECT
                           P.OBJECTID
                           ,P.ATTR2817 'Practice'
                           ,P.FK2818 'RelatedSite'
                           ,P.ATTR2882 'Onboarding Date'
                           ,M.MEMO 'Notes'
                            FROM HSI.RMOBJECTINSTANCE1230 P INNER JOIN HSI.RMMEMO M ON P.FK2818 = M.MEMOID";
        string queryPro = @"SELECT 
                           P.OBJECTID
                           ,P.ATTR2919 'Provider'
                           ,P.ATTR2920 'Start Date'
                           ,P.FK2921 'RelatedPractice'
                           ,P.FK2922 'RelatedClient'
                            FROM HSI.RMOBJECTINSTANCE1249 P";
        #endregion 


        string query = "";

        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString))
        {
            if (ddlCli.SelectedIndex > 0)
            {
                try
                {
                    demoCli.Visible = true;

                    query = queryCli + " WHERE C.ATTR2815 = '" + ddlCli.SelectedValue + "'";

                    // create data adapter
                    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(query, conn);
                    // this will query your database and return the result to your datatable

                    DataSet myDataSet = new DataSet();
                    da.Fill(myDataSet);
                    lblCli.Text = myDataSet.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Client"].ToString();
                    lblCliDate.Text = myDataSet.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Onboarding Date"].ToString();
                    lblCliCont.Text = myDataSet.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Contact Information"].ToString();
                    lblCliNotes.Text = myDataSet.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Notes"].ToString();

                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    string error = ex.Message;
                }
            }

            if (ddlSit.SelectedIndex > 0)
            {
                try
                {
                    demoSit.Visible = true;
                    query = querySit + " WHERE S.ATTR2819 = '" + ddlSit.SelectedValue + "'";

                    // create data adapter
                    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(query, conn);
                    // this will query your database and return the result to your datatable

                    DataSet myDataSet = new DataSet();
                    da.Fill(myDataSet);
                    lblSit.Text = myDataSet.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Site"].ToString();
                    lblSitRC.Text = myDataSet.Tables[0].Rows[0]["RelatedClient"].ToString();
                    lblSitAdd.Text = myDataSet.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Address"].ToString();
                    lblSitCity.Text = myDataSet.Tables[0].Rows[0]["City"].ToString();
                    lblSitSt.Text = myDataSet.Tables[0].Rows[0]["State"].ToString();
                    lblSitzip.Text = myDataSet.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Zip"].ToString();
                    lblSitOnDate.Text = myDataSet.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Onboarding Date"].ToString();
                    lblSitNotes.Text = myDataSet.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Notes"].ToString();

                    //upGenTaskCli.Update();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    string error = ex.Message;
                }
            }
            if (ddlPra.SelectedIndex > 0)
            {
                try
                {
                    demoPra.Visible = true;
                    query = queryPra + " WHERE P.ATTR2817 = '" + ddlPra.SelectedValue + "'";

                    // create data adapter
                    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(query, conn);
                    // this will query your database and return the result to your datatable

                    DataSet myDataSet = new DataSet();
                    da.Fill(myDataSet);
                    lblPra.Text = myDataSet.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Client"].ToString();
                    lblPraRS.Text = myDataSet.Tables[0].Rows[0]["RelatedSite"].ToString();
                    lblPraOnDate.Text = myDataSet.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Onboarding Date"].ToString();
                    lblPraNotes.Text = myDataSet.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Notes"].ToString();

                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    string error = ex.Message;
                }
            }
            if (ddlPro.SelectedIndex > 0)
            {
                try
                {
                    demoPro.Visible = true;
                    query = queryPro + " WHERE P.ATTR2919 = '" + ddlPro.SelectedValue + "'";

                    // create data adapter
                    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(query, conn);
                    // this will query your database and return the result to your datatable

                    DataSet myDataSet = new DataSet();
                    da.Fill(myDataSet);
                    lblPro.Text = myDataSet.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Provider"].ToString();
                    lblProStart.Text = myDataSet.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Start Date"].ToString();
                    lblProRP.Text = myDataSet.Tables[0].Rows[0]["RelatedPractice"].ToString();
                    lblProRC.Text = myDataSet.Tables[0].Rows[0]["RelatedClient"].ToString();

                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    string error = ex.Message;
                }
            }

            upGenTaskCli.Update();
        }
}
```

I added breakpoints for these lines:

```
lblCli.Text = myDataSet.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Client"].ToString();
lblCliDate.Text = myDataSet.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Onboarding Date"].ToString();
lblCliCont.Text = myDataSet.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Contact Information"].ToString();
lblCliNotes.Text = myDataSet.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Notes"].ToString();
```

And hovering the mouse over them, displays the text data but the `upGenTaskCli` is not updating to show the data.

I receive this error:

```
0x800a139e - Microsoft JScript runtime error: Sys.InvalidOperationException: Could not find UpdatePanel with ID 'upGenTaskCli'. If it is being updated dynamically then it must be inside another UpdatePanel.
```

How do I resolve the issue?

Comment: what does the error message say? Have you tried doing what the error message says? lol :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since its a JS visibilty error, Try to put your Update Panel inside another update panel
like this:

//this is how your view should look like

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="pnlParent" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="upGenTaskCli" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional" ClientIDMode="Static">
            <ContentTemplate>
                Client: <asp:Label ID="lblCli" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
                <br />
                Onboarding Date: <asp:Label ID="lblCliDate" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
                <br />
                Contact Information: <asp:Label ID="lblCliCont" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
                <br />
                Notes: <asp:Label ID="lblCliNotes" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" Text=""></asp:Label>
                <br />
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
</contentTemplate>
</updatePanel>
```

so in your code behind do the following :

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript
                       (this, typeof(Page), "UpdateMsg", "$(document).ready(function(){$('#upGenTaskCli').hide();});", true);
            }
        }
```

//and then in your button Logic add the following line in the If clause :

```
protected void btnFilter_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if (ddlCli.SelectedIndex > 0)
        {
            try
            {

                query = queryCli + " WHERE C.ATTR2815 = '" + ddlCli.SelectedValue + "'";

                // create data adapter
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(query, conn);
                // this will query your database and return the result to your datatable

                DataSet myDataSet = new DataSet();
                da.Fill(myDataSet);
                lblCli.Text = myDataSet.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Client"].ToString();
                lblCliDate.Text = myDataSet.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Onboarding Date"].ToString();
                lblCliCont.Text = myDataSet.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Contact Information"].ToString();
                lblCliNotes.Text = myDataSet.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Notes"].ToString();

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                string error = ex.Message;
            }
 ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock
                        (this, typeof(System.Web.UI.Page), "MyJSFunction", "$('#upGenTaskCli').toggle();", true);

}
```

//it should work

Comment: remove these two excess panels : <asp:Panel ID="pageTab8" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server">
    <asp:Panel ID="demoCli" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" BorderWidth="2" BorderColor="#FF0000">

Comment: I hid `pnlParent` on page load (`pnlParent.Visible = false;`) and inside the `if (ddlCli.SelectedIndex > 0)` I show the `pnlParent` (`pnlParent.Visible = true;`) and I am getting the same error again :/

Comment: Do I also have to set the `upGenTaskCli` visibility to true in the `IF` statement as well?

Comment: Actually that didn't help either. What I am looking to do is hide the pnlParent on page load. When I click the button display that panel. I get the same error.

Comment: well, if u hide the whole panel, how can JS find the element then, u know when an element visibility is set to false, it means it doesnt exist from JS standpoint

Comment: This is my code: http://jsfiddle.net/5xanompv/ (Can't use pastebin for some reason but this is how I have it) Can you please let me know where I went wrong... Thanks.

Comment: WOW awesome. So if I have to show/hide multiples, I would add multiples `ScriptBlock`?

Comment: Was waiting to see if you would answer.